# GCP HA VPN to Fortigate (AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, fortigate

I'm having an issue configuring a site to site vpn from GCP to Fortigate.

I'm configuring a 1 tunnel HA VPN as a test before building in production.

My fortigate is behind an external fireawll, IPSEC vpn is configure with NAT.

According to debugs on the Fortigate, Phase 1 and Phase 2 are negotiated and established, Fortigate sends AUTH_RESPONSE and gets reply from the GCP side saying AUTHENTICATION_FAILED.

The status on GCP side is showing:

First Handshake.  Allocating resources. VPN tunnel will start soon.

Has anyone any ideas why im getting AUTHENTICATION_FAILED on GCP side?

Thanks
Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what the issue may be I would suggest looking at these two Google Public documents. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-ha-vpn-with-fortigate) describes how to use HA VPN with Fortigate, and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithFortinetFortiGate300C.pdf) is a setup guide. Within these two documents you should be able to configure your authentication to work with GCP.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.I think ive found the issue.

https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat

authentication of '[PEER GATEWAY PRIVATE IP]' with pre-shared key successful constraint check failed.
identity '[PEER GATEWAY PUBLIC IP]' required.
selected peer config 'vpn_[PEER GATEWAY PUBLIC IP]' inacceptable: constraint checking failed.

GCP is expecting the FG to identify itself as the public IP when its behind NAT. anyone else came across this issue?  i have already configued the public ip as the localid but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has been a [known issue](https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=182357) for quite some time.  FortiOS 6.4.6 did add a field called "Local ID" to override the default IP address, but unfortunately it [incorrectly sets the identity type as FQDN](https://layer77.net/2021/09/28/2095/) and Google will reject the VPN session for that reason.  I reported this to FortiGate over a year ago and they were unwilling to accept it as a bug, instead saying I needed to sign a large contract and then make a feature request.

Currently, the only workaround is to give the FortiGate a public IP address.  Or, use AWS as they'll accept the private IP.